# get create-react-app to watch folder outside of src with `yarn start` command

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, bit-ui

I've started using [bit](http://bit.dev) so that I can reuse common components across different react projects.

This is great, but I've run into a rather annoying situation when I want to modify one of my bit components.

They live in the `components` folder at the root of my project's directory.  This outside of the `src` folder which I guess is what cra is watching when I run the `yarn start` command.

So when I modify the component code, nothing happens and I have to rerun the `yarn start` command to see any of the effects of my changes.

Is it possible to tell cra to watch folders other than `src` for changes and trigger an update?

Comment: In the [bit docs](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/quick-start#add-files) the add examples are all in the `src` dir can't you just do that? Otherwise I would think you have to eject the app to configure another dir.

Comment: the problem is that when I add a component from bit to my project it automatically puts them in a `components` folder outside of the `src` folder.  Perhaps I can configure that location...